# C# Comparing adjacent values in a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, project

The path starts at row index 80, column index 0. I have to create a path to the other edge of the map (column index 199). I cannot go back to a previous cell I visited, I must do a comparison of the cells that are only adjacent to the current cell but I cannot move back a column, I must keep moving forward or I can move "up" or "down" in the current column I am in. I am finding the least amount of difference between the cells.

To represent the path, I have to store either a (/) to represent you moved up and to the right, () to represent I moved down and to the right, (-) to represent I moved to the right, or (|) to represent I moved up or down.

Here is what I have so far:

I am not sure on how to compare the adjacent cells. I think I need a couple if statements but I couldn't quite figure it out. 
As far as representing the path, I am really not sure what to use. I tried to make a separate method to store those characters into another 2d array but couldn't get it to work.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] path = new string[116, 200];
        short[,] map = arrayMethod();

        int rowIndex = 80;
        int colIndex = 0;
        int positionOfX = 0;
        int positionOfY = 0;
        short minValue = short.MaxValue;

        while (colIndex != 199)
        {
            for (short l = -1; l < 2; l++)
            {
                for (short k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                {
                    if (map[l+ rowIndex, k+colIndex] < minValue)
                    {
                        positionOfX = l;
                        positionOfY = k;
                        minValue = map[l, k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Method to store data into 2d array
    public static short[,] arrayMethod()
    {
        short[,] map = new short[116, 200];

        string fileName = "land.csv";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(fileName, 
    FileMode.Open));
        string nextLine;
        int partsCounter = 0;
        while ((nextLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = nextLine.Split(',');

            for (int cols = 0; cols < 200; cols++)
            {
                map[partsCounter, cols] = Convert.ToInt16(parts[cols]);
            }
            partsCounter++;
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not meant to be a "do it for me" coding site. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not asking anybody to do it for me. I am looking for help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I am a little stuck on how to compare adjacent cells.  I just added:           
                       if (map[l+ rowIndex, k+colIndex] < minValue)
                        {
                            positionOfX = l;
                            positionOfY = k;
                            minValue = map[l, k];
                        }

Comment: It isn't a site to hire people either. Formulate a question. I would guess that the code you have is not working... in that case  us what is it doing and how that differs from what you expect, then we can tell you how to fix it. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47585586/edit).

Comment: Nowhere did I mention anything about hiring someone? I am asking for some help with this project. I gave the description of what I am required to do. I am stuck on a certain part and asked for help.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you basically list a spec sheet. It makes someone coming across your question think that you haven't done any work. Yes, you did add your code, however, the way your question is formatted it leads us to believe that you do not have a specific error and you do not want to do any work. As @Theraot mentioned it would help you out to edit your question according to the [how to ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that way we can help you with your exact problem :)

Comment: I'll take a look at the article and edit it soon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

About choosing a path, you say:

> I am finding the least amount of difference between the cells.

I will come back to that.

---

About comparing adjacent cells, given that each cell is represented by a `short` in array, that should be simple numeric comparison.

The crux of the problem, I beleive, is finding the adjacent cells.

Well, you have a 2D grid, and you have the coordinates for one cell...

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     | x,y |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

You can find the adjacent cells by changing the coordinates by 1:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |x,y-1|     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |x-1,y| x,y |x+1,y|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |x,y+1|     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Note: I am representing the coordinates assuming the origin is in the top left corner. That is the standard convention for computer graphics. It may not apply in your case. Regardless of that, these continue to be your adjacent cells.

If we should not go back to the prior column (the number of the column must always increase) I think it safe to ignore that one adjacent:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |x,y-1|     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     | x,y |x+1,y|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |x,y+1|     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

---

We can do this:

```
// the map
short[,] map = arrayMethod();

// map dimensions

int numRows = map.GetLength(0);
int numCols = map.GetLength(1);

// current position
int rowIndex = 80;
int colIndex = 0;

while (colIndex < numCols - 1)
{
    var current = map[rowIndex, colIndex];
    if (rowIndex > 0)
    {
         // We are not at the low row edge
         var adjacent = map[rowIndex - 1, colIndex];
         Compare(current, adjacent);
    }
    if (rowIndex < numRows - 1)
    {
        // We are not at the high row edge
        var adjacent = map[rowIndex + 1, colIndex];
        Compare(current, adjacent);
    }
    /*if (colIndex > 0)
    {
         // We are not at the low column edge
         var adjacent = map[rowIndex, colIndex - 1];
         Compare(current, adjacent);
    }*/
    if (/*colIndex < numCols - 1*/ true)
    {
        // We are not at the high column edge
         var adjacent = map[rowIndex, colIndex + 1];
         Compare(current, adjacent);
    }
    // ... update rowIndex, colIndex
}
```

Here each `if` block correspond to one of the adjacent cells, the reason to have an `if` is to check if we are not at the edge, because - as I said earlier - if you are at the edge, there is no adjacent in that direction.

Also notice that I have made into comments the `if` that corresponds to go back in columns. I have also made into comments the last conditional, that is because the `while` is already checking that one.

I am using a `Compare` method to represent whatever comparison you want to do - will come back to that. Also notice I am not updating `rowIndex` and `colIndex`, what you have above is an infinite loop. To fix that, I suggest to treat the adjacent cells as a list, it will make things easier later...

Addendum: No, you do not need a list. It can be done without it, yet it leads to more repetition, will be harder to read, and will more error prone.

```
// the map
short[,] map = arrayMethod();

// map dimensions

int numRows = map.GetLength(0);
int numCols = map.GetLength(1);

// current position
int rowIndex = 80;
int colIndex = 0;

while (colIndex < numCols - 1)
{
    var current = map[rowIndex, colIndex];
    var adjacents = new List<Tuple</*row*/ short, /*column*/ short>>();
    if (rowIndex > 0)
    {
         adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex - 1, colIndex));
    }
    if (rowIndex < numRows - 1)
    {
         adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex + 1, colIndex));
    }
    adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex, colIndex + 1));
    foreach (var adjacent in adjacents)
    {
        Compare(map[adjacent.Item1, adjacent.Item2], current);
    }
    // ... update rowIndex, colIndex
}
```

Now...

> I am finding the least amount of difference between the cells.

That I understand as the absolute value of the difference, and I am infering you want to minimize this (the requirements are not very clear on that).

Under that understanding, we can implement the comparison:

```
foreach (var adjacent in adjacents)
{
    var diff = Math.Abs(map[adjacent.Item1, adjacent.Item2] - current);
}
```

And pick our destination:

```
Tuple<short, short> best;
short bestDiff;
foreach (var adjacent in adjacents)
{
    var diff = Math.Abs(map[adjacent.Item1, adjacent.Item2] - current);
    if (best == null || bestDiff > diff)
    {
        best = adjacent;
        bestDiff = diff;
    }
}
rowIndex = best.Item1;
colIndex = best.Item2;
```

---

Now, granted, you should not go back a column or back to the prior cell. Thus, you would have to keep track of your last position, so you do not check that one.

```
// the map
short[,] map = arrayMethod();

// map dimensions

int numRows = map.GetLength(0);
int numCols = map.GetLength(1);

// current position
int rowIndex = 80;
int colIndex = 0;

// old position
int rowIndexOld = 80;
int colIndexOld = -1; // <-- placing it outside the map

while (colIndex < numCols - 1)
{
    var current = map[rowIndex, colIndex];
    var adjacents = new List<Tuple<short, short>>();
    if (rowIndex > 0 && rowIndexOld != rowIndex - 1 && colIndexOld != colIndex)
    {
         adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex - 1, colIndex));
    }
    if (rowIndex < numRows - 1 && rowIndexOld != rowIndex + 1 && colIndexOld != colIndex)
    {
         adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex + 1, colIndex));
    }
    if (rowIndexOld != rowIndex && colIndexOld != colIndex + 1)
    {
        adjacents.Add(Tuple.Create(rowIndex, colIndex + 1));
    }
    rowIndexOld = rowIndex;
    colIndexOld = colIndex;
    // etc
}
```

---

Of course, you would add your logic to pick the path and to write it to the output.

To be honest, I do not fully understand the requirements... why do you have notations for representing diagonal movement if you can only move forward, up, and down? Anyway, if you the diagonals, that is not much harder:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |x-1,y-1| x,y-1 |x+1,y-1|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       | x-1,y |  x,y  | x+1,y |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |x-1,y+1| x,y+1 |x+1,y+1|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Am sure you can work out the code for that, is just more of the same. Those would be more adjacent to check and to add to the list.

I hope you understand the requirements better than I do.

---

Some suggestions:

- You may consider to use a type to represent the position in the map. Since you are using pairs of row and column variables a lot, it makes sense to have a type for that... I am just using `Tuple<short, short>`, but you can do better.
- You may want to encapsulate the logic of checking if an adjacent is not the old position and adding it to the list. The benefit is to make the code more readable and make it less error prone (for example, you would not accidentally check for one adjacent but adding a different one, which is something that may slip by in copy & paste).

---

Addendum: I guess the output would be a string, and you can build it with `StringBuilder`. The character you add depends on which adjacent you pick. Perhaps a structure that holds both the adjacent coordinates and the character to use if you pick it would make things easier. Or do you need to draw the path in the console? because that is something entirely different.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!                                                      
Sorry if I was unclear with some requirements. The path is allowed to go up-down, left-right, or diagonal (up and right or down and right).

Comment: I am not familiar with tuples at all. We have not learned anything about them in class.